# Did Videl go Super Saiyan in Episode 9 of Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

At first I thought it was just glowing from the others' Ki but her hair remained yellow after all the Ki glowing stopped. So did she go Super Saiyan?

[image]

Comment: i haven't seen Super but could it actually be Pan's Ki Energy? Pan was one of the Saiyen's needed to allow Goku to become Super Saiyen God in Battle of Gods, despite not actually being born

Comment: I also feel that it seemed more like Pans residual energy and agree with the above poster. I saw the episode yesterday and thought the same thing and thought about it all afternoon until I saw this post lol

Comment: Her eye didn't turn green and eye brown didn't change proof it's not a Super Saiyan. It's just her hair turn gold somehow and it also did not spike upwards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Videl didn't go Super Saiyan. In order to become a Super Saiyan, you kind of need to be part of the Saiyan race.

In the movie Battle of the Gods, Videl joined the circle to pass energy to Goku to turn him into a Super Saiyan God since 5 Saiyans needed to pass their energy to a single Saiyan recipient. Videl joined because Pan is in her womb, and the latter is quarter-Saiyan.

Most likely Videl's hair is just showing off residual energy from Pan. Does this mean Pan will become a Super Saiyan this time? We don't know.

Though, largely, the reason I'm saying Videl didn't transform into a Super Saiyan is because she isn't a member of the Saiyan race, so even if she can, "Use" Pan's power as a Super Saiyan to fight at some point later in DBSuper (which, talk about dangerous things for mothers to do while pregnant lol), Videl still won't be a Super Saiyan. She'd be a human borrowing the power of one until that child is born.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that she only *turned Super Saiyan* in the anime. In chapter 4 of the manga, she stayed the same old Videl. If Akira did not participate in the making of the anime I would have said that Videl turning Super Saiyan would not be canon, but he does participate. So now it just is confusing why they chose to approach it differently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Videl is clearly a human, not a Saiyan. She doesn't have Saiyan blood inside of her, she has human blood genes. Pan is inside Videl's womb, giving her power to her grandfather, Goku to become a Super Saiyan God. But we might going to see Pan going to transform into a Super Saiyan later in the Dragon Ball Super series.